# how to map the response of getlistitems web service of sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, xml-parsing, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have basic question on sharepoint application.

There are some webservices provided by MS to access sharepoint services.

lets take example of GetListItems service.

i wanted to know, how to identify from XML parser that, a item is folder or file? what Tag i should look into to recognize the item as folder or file

how to get attributes of a file or folder(last accesed date, read only etc etc).

Please guide me in right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical response from the web service looks like below:

```
<rs:data ItemCount="4">
  <z:row ows_Modified="2012-05-31 12:34:01" ows_ContentTypeId="0x01200082B0C5829FE047A1BF58F68DA1DAB12500C7BCD99F82ACA340A0131D59CE62371B" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_ID="1" ows_Created_x0020_Date="1;#2012-05-31 12:34:01" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_FileRef="1;#depts/it/Lists/CTADocuments/mygroup" />
  <z:row ows_Modified="2012-05-31 12:36:51" ows_ContentTypeId="0x01200082B0C5829FE047A1BF58F68DA1DAB12500C7BCD99F82ACA340A0131D59CE62371B" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_ID="2" ows_Created_x0020_Date="2;#2012-05-31 12:36:51" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_FileRef="2;#depts/it/Lists/CTADocuments/mygroup/another one" />
  <z:row ows_Modified="2012-05-31 17:49:45" ows_ContentTypeId="0x010100EB5D8789C471B04E80E2A7481607C23B" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_ID="9" ows_Created_x0020_Date="9;#2012-05-31 17:49:45" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_FileRef="9;#depts/it/Lists/CTADocuments/Just_the_Essentials_Publishing.master" />
  <z:row ows_Modified="2012-06-07 17:05:11" ows_ContentTypeId="0x010100EB5D8789C471B04E80E2A7481607C23B" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_ID="10" ows_Created_x0020_Date="10;#2012-06-07 17:05:11" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_FileRef="10;#depts/it/Lists/CTADocuments/mygroup/another one/junk.txt" />
</rs:data>
```

First two z:row are folders (look at the ContentTypeId) the others are documents.

ContentTypeIds: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543822.aspx

Comment: Hi RoMaiac thanks for this reply. Thanks for sharing the link as well

Comment: will all the response from sharepoint server have a XML tag with name "ows_ContentTypeId". I did some google and found its not the case. If this tag is not there how i will come to know contenttype?

Comment: can somebody answer my querry, if my question is wrong, let me correct it.my question is simple if "ows_ContentTypeId" tag is not there in XML response which we got from sharepoint server, how we will come to know the contenttype.

Comment: When you call GetListItems you can specify what ViewFields you want in the response. Force "ContentType" to be one of your fields: `<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /></ViewFields>`